# Trouble installing SQL Developer OE (Order Entry) sample database

Tags: oracle

I've been at this for literally hours. I've followed the instructions here - http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/COMSC/installation.htm#COMSC109 - but I get the following when arriving at the 'Installing Schema OE and Subschema OC' section and doing as it says, running oe_main.sql;

```
specify password for OE as parameter 1:
old:DEFINE pass     = &1
new:DEFINE pass     = oe

specify default tablespeace for OE as parameter 2:
old:DEFINE tbs      = &2
new:DEFINE tbs      = OE

specify temporary tablespace for OE as parameter 3:
old:DEFINE ttbs     = &3
new:DEFINE ttbs     = temp

specify password for HR as parameter 4:
old:DEFINE passhr   = &4
new:DEFINE passhr   = hr

specify password for SYS as parameter 5:
old:DEFINE pass_sys = &5
new:DEFINE pass_sys = manager

specify directory path for the data files as parameter 6:
old:DEFINE data_path = &6
new:DEFINE data_path = C:\

writeable directory path for the log files as parameter 7:
old:DEFINE log_path = &7
new:DEFINE log_path = C:\

specify version as parameter 8:
old:DEFINE vrs = &8
new:DEFINE vrs = 5

old:DEFINE spool_file = &log_path.oe_oc_&vrs..log
new:DEFINE spool_file = C:\oe_oc_5.log
old:SPOOL &spool_file
new:SPOOL C:\oe_oc_5.log

Error starting at line : 75 in command -
DROP USER oe CASCADE
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01918: user 'OE' does not exist
01918. 00000 -  "user '%s' does not exist"
*Cause:    User does not exist in the system.
*Action:   Verify the user name is correct.
old:CREATE USER oe IDENTIFIED BY &pass
new:CREATE USER oe IDENTIFIED BY oe

Error starting at line : 86 in command -
CREATE USER oe IDENTIFIED BY oe
Error at Command Line : 86 Column : 30
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
01031. 00000 -  "insufficient privileges"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to perform a database operation without
           the necessary privileges.
*Action:   Ask your database administrator or designated security
           administrator to grant you the necessary privileges
old:ALTER USER oe DEFAULT TABLESPACE &tbs QUOTA UNLIMITED ON &tbs
new:ALTER USER oe DEFAULT TABLESPACE temp QUOTA UNLIMITED ON temp

Error starting at line : 88 in command -
ALTER USER oe DEFAULT TABLESPACE &tbs QUOTA UNLIMITED ON &tbs
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
01031. 00000 -  "insufficient privileges"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to perform a database operation without
           the necessary privileges.
*Action:   Ask your database administrator or designated security
           administrator to grant you the necessary privileges
old:ALTER USER oe TEMPORARY TABLESPACE &ttbs
new:ALTER USER oe TEMPORARY TABLESPACE temp

Error starting at line : 90 in command -
ALTER USER oe TEMPORARY TABLESPACE &ttbs
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
01031. 00000 -  "insufficient privileges"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to perform a database operation without
           the necessary privileges.
*Action:   Ask your database administrator or designated security
           administrator to grant you the necessary privileges

Error starting at line : 92 in command -
GRANT CREATE SESSION, CREATE SYNONYM, CREATE VIEW TO oe
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
01031. 00000 -  "insufficient privileges"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to perform a database operation without
           the necessary privileges.
*Action:   Ask your database administrator or designated security
           administrator to grant you the necessary privileges
Error starting at line : 93 in command -
GRANT CREATE DATABASE LINK, ALTER SESSION TO oe
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
01031. 00000 -  "insufficient privileges"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to perform a database operation without
           the necessary privileges.
*Action:   Ask your database administrator or designated security
           administrator to grant you the necessary privileges

Error starting at line : 94 in command -
GRANT RESOURCE TO oe
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
01031. 00000 -  "insufficient privileges"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to perform a database operation without
           the necessary privileges.
*Action:   Ask your database administrator or designated security
           administrator to grant you the necessary privileges

Error starting at line : 95 in command -
GRANT CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW  TO oe
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
01031. 00000 -  "insufficient privileges"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to perform a database operation without
           the necessary privileges.
*Action:   Ask your database administrator or designated security
           administrator to grant you the necessary privileges

Error starting at line : 96 in command -
GRANT QUERY REWRITE             TO oe
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
01031. 00000 -  "insufficient privileges"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to perform a database operation without
           the necessary privileges.
*Action:   Ask your database administrator or designated security
           administrator to grant you the necessary privileges
old:CONNECT sys/&pass_sys AS SYSDBA
new:CONNECT sys/manager AS SYSDBA
Connected

Error starting at line : 103 in command -
GRANT execute ON sys.dbms_stats TO oe
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01917: user or role 'OE' does not exist
01917. 00000 -  "user or role '%s' does not exist"
*Cause:    There is not a user or role by that name.
*Action:   Re-specify the name.
old:CONNECT hr/&passhr
new:CONNECT hr/hr
Connected

Error starting at line : 110 in command -
GRANT REFERENCES, SELECT ON employees TO oe
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01917: user or role 'OE' does not exist
01917. 00000 -  "user or role '%s' does not exist"
*Cause:    There is not a user or role by that name.
*Action:   Re-specify the name.

Error starting at line : 111 in command -
GRANT REFERENCES, SELECT ON countries TO oe
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01917: user or role 'OE' does not exist
01917. 00000 -  "user or role '%s' does not exist"
*Cause:    There is not a user or role by that name.
*Action:   Re-specify the name.

Error starting at line : 112 in command -
GRANT REFERENCES, SELECT ON locations TO oe
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01917: user or role 'OE' does not exist
01917. 00000 -  "user or role '%s' does not exist"
*Cause:    There is not a user or role by that name.
*Action:   Re-specify the name.

Error starting at line : 113 in command -
GRANT SELECT ON jobs TO oe
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01917: user or role 'OE' does not exist
01917. 00000 -  "user or role '%s' does not exist"
*Cause:    There is not a user or role by that name.
*Action:   Re-specify the name.
Error starting at line : 114 in command -
GRANT SELECT ON job_history TO oe
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01917: user or role 'OE' does not exist
01917. 00000 -  "user or role '%s' does not exist"
*Cause:    There is not a user or role by that name.
*Action:   Re-specify the name.

Error starting at line : 115 in command -
GRANT SELECT ON departments TO oe
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01917: user or role 'OE' does not exist
01917. 00000 -  "user or role '%s' does not exist"
*Cause:    There is not a user or role by that name.
*Action:   Re-specify the name.
old:CONNECT oe/&pass
new:CONNECT oe/oe

Error starting at line : 122 in command -
CONNECT oe/&pass
Error report -
Connection Failed
Commit
```

The problems start with 'User 'OE' doesn't exist'. Any Oracle DBA available for some guidance?

Running this in Oracle SQL Developer, and tried the same in SQLPlus - same results.

EDIT:

Now seeing this;

```
specify password for OE as parameter 1:
old:DEFINE pass     = &1
new:DEFINE pass     = oe

specify default tablespeace for OE as parameter 2:
old:DEFINE tbs      = &2
new:DEFINE tbs      = OE

specify temporary tablespace for OE as parameter 3:
old:DEFINE ttbs     = &3
new:DEFINE ttbs     = temp

specify password for HR as parameter 4:
old:DEFINE passhr   = &4
new:DEFINE passhr   = hr

specify password for SYS as parameter 5:
old:DEFINE pass_sys = &5
new:DEFINE pass_sys = password

specify directory path for the data files as parameter 6:
old:DEFINE data_path = &6
new:DEFINE data_path = C:\

writeable directory path for the log files as parameter 7:
old:DEFINE log_path = &7
new:DEFINE log_path = C:\log

specify version as parameter 8:
old:DEFINE vrs = &8
new:DEFINE vrs = v3

old:DEFINE spool_file = &log_path.oe_oc_&vrs..log
new:DEFINE spool_file = C:\logoe_oc_v3.log
old:SPOOL &spool_file
new:SPOOL C:\logoe_oc_v3.log
user OE dropped.
old:CREATE USER oe IDENTIFIED BY &pass
new:CREATE USER oe IDENTIFIED BY oe
user OE created.
old:ALTER USER oe DEFAULT TABLESPACE &tbs QUOTA UNLIMITED ON &tbs
new:ALTER USER oe DEFAULT TABLESPACE OE QUOTA UNLIMITED ON OE
Error starting at line : 96 in command -
ALTER USER oe DEFAULT TABLESPACE &tbs QUOTA UNLIMITED ON &tbs
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00959: tablespace 'OE' does not exist
00959. 00000 -  "tablespace '%s' does not exist"
*Cause:    
*Action:
old:ALTER USER oe TEMPORARY TABLESPACE &ttbs
new:ALTER USER oe TEMPORARY TABLESPACE temp
user OE altered.
GRANT succeeded.
GRANT succeeded.
GRANT succeeded.
GRANT succeeded.
GRANT succeeded.
old:CONNECT sys/&pass_sys AS SYSDBA
new:CONNECT sys/password AS SYSDBA
Connected
GRANT succeeded.
old:CONNECT hr/&passhr
new:CONNECT hr/hr
Connected
GRANT succeeded.
GRANT succeeded.
GRANT succeeded.
GRANT succeeded.
GRANT succeeded.
GRANT succeeded.
old:CONNECT oe/&pass
new:CONNECT oe/oe
Connected
session SET altered.
session SET altered.
old:DEFINE vscript = ?/demo/schema/order_entry/coe_&vrs
new:DEFINE vscript = ?/demo/schema/order_entry/coe_v3
old:@&vscript &vrs &pass &pass_sys
new:@?/demo/schema/order_entry/coe_v3 v3 oe password

Error starting at line : 139 in command -
@&vscript &vrs &pass &pass_sys
Error report -
Unable to open file: "?/demo/schema/order_entry/coe_v3.sql"
old:DEFINE vscript = ?/demo/schema/order_entry/loe_&vrs
new:DEFINE vscript = ?/demo/schema/order_entry/loe_v3
old:@&vscript &vrs &data_path &log_path &pass
new:@?/demo/schema/order_entry/loe_v3 v3 C:\ C:\log oe

Error starting at line : 146 in command -
@&vscript &vrs &data_path &log_path &pass
Error report -
Unable to open file: "?/demo/schema/order_entry/loe_v3.sql"
old:DEFINE vscript = ?/demo/schema/order_entry/poe_&vrs
new:DEFINE vscript = ?/demo/schema/order_entry/poe_v3
old:@&vscript &vrs
new:@?/demo/schema/order_entry/poe_v3 v3

Error starting at line : 153 in command -
@&vscript &vrs 
Error report -
Unable to open file: "?/demo/schema/order_entry/poe_v3.sql"

Error starting at line : 159 in command -
@?/demo/schema/order_entry/oc_main
Error report -
Unable to open file: "?/demo/schema/order_entry/oc_main.sql"

Error starting at line : 165 in command -
@?/demo/schema/order_entry/oe_analz
Error report -
Unable to open file: "?/demo/schema/order_entry/oe_analz.sql"
Connection created by CONNECT script command disconnected
```

The first error is 'tablespace 'OE' does not exist' - surely the whole point is to create it? And then line above appears to be trying to do that.

There's also errors retrieving the data (Unable to open file) - is that because I specified only C:\ (incidentally when I have this working I'll change that, I just got fed up with copying and pasting the complete path every time)? I've tried specifying C:\app\Hamish\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\demo\schema\order_entry which is where the data is but I get the same result as above.

EDIT 2:

Now I'm seeing this;

As per my comments to the guys who gave feedback below - am I supposed to put the /demo/... somewhere in the SQL Developer directory so it can automatically find the files?

```
specify password for OE as parameter 1:
old:DEFINE pass     = &1
new:DEFINE pass     = oe

specify default tablespeace for OE as parameter 2:
old:DEFINE tbs      = &2
new:DEFINE tbs      = users

specify temporary tablespace for OE as parameter 3:
old:DEFINE ttbs     = &3
new:DEFINE ttbs     = temp

specify password for HR as parameter 4:
old:DEFINE passhr   = &4
new:DEFINE passhr   = hr

specify password for SYS as parameter 5:
old:DEFINE pass_sys = &5
new:DEFINE pass_sys = password

specify directory path for the data files as parameter 6:
old:DEFINE data_path = &6
new:DEFINE data_path = C:/

writeable directory path for the log files as parameter 7:
old:DEFINE log_path = &7
new:DEFINE log_path = C:/log

specify version as parameter 8:
old:DEFINE vrs = &8
new:DEFINE vrs = v3

old:DEFINE spool_file = &log_path.oe_oc_&vrs..log
new:DEFINE spool_file = C:/logoe_oc_v3.log
old:SPOOL &spool_file
new:SPOOL C:/logoe_oc_v3.log
user OE dropped.
old:CREATE USER oe IDENTIFIED BY &pass
new:CREATE USER oe IDENTIFIED BY oe
user OE created.
old:ALTER USER oe DEFAULT TABLESPACE &tbs QUOTA UNLIMITED ON &tbs
new:ALTER USER oe DEFAULT TABLESPACE users QUOTA UNLIMITED ON users
user OE altered.
old:ALTER USER oe TEMPORARY TABLESPACE &ttbs
new:ALTER USER oe TEMPORARY TABLESPACE temp
user OE altered.
GRANT succeeded.
GRANT succeeded.
GRANT succeeded.
GRANT succeeded.
GRANT succeeded.
old:CONNECT sys/&pass_sys AS SYSDBA
new:CONNECT sys/password AS SYSDBA
Connected
GRANT succeeded.
old:CONNECT hr/&passhr
new:CONNECT hr/hr
Connected
GRANT succeeded.
GRANT succeeded.
GRANT succeeded.
GRANT succeeded.
GRANT succeeded.
GRANT succeeded.
old:CONNECT oe/&pass
new:CONNECT oe/oe
Connected
session SET altered.
session SET altered.
old:DEFINE vscript = ?/demo/schema/order_entry/coe_&vrs
new:DEFINE vscript = ?/demo/schema/order_entry/coe_v3
old:@&vscript &vrs &pass &pass_sys
new:@?/demo/schema/order_entry/coe_v3 v3 oe password

Error starting at line : 131 in command -
@&vscript &vrs &pass &pass_sys
Error report -
Unable to open file: "?/demo/schema/order_entry/coe_v3.sql"
old:DEFINE vscript = ?/demo/schema/order_entry/loe_&vrs
new:DEFINE vscript = ?/demo/schema/order_entry/loe_v3
old:@&vscript &vrs &data_path &log_path &pass
new:@?/demo/schema/order_entry/loe_v3 v3 C:/ C:/log oe

Error starting at line : 138 in command -
@&vscript &vrs &data_path &log_path &pass
Error report -
Unable to open file: "?/demo/schema/order_entry/loe_v3.sql"
old:DEFINE vscript = ?/demo/schema/order_entry/poe_&vrs
new:DEFINE vscript = ?/demo/schema/order_entry/poe_v3
old:@&vscript &vrs
new:@?/demo/schema/order_entry/poe_v3 v3

Error starting at line : 145 in command -
@&vscript &vrs 
Error report -
Unable to open file: "?/demo/schema/order_entry/poe_v3.sql"

Error starting at line : 151 in command -
@?/demo/schema/order_entry/oc_main
Error report -
Unable to open file: "?/demo/schema/order_entry/oc_main.sql"

Error starting at line : 157 in command -
@?/demo/schema/order_entry/oe_analz
Error report -
Unable to open file: "?/demo/schema/order_entry/oe_analz.sql"
Connection created by CONNECT script command disconnected
```

EDIT 3: I went into each file and manually changed the @? for @C:/[path to..]/demo/schema ... etc. Once it could find the files the process completed but it was painful amending every single @? - if there's an easier way to do this I'd like to hear it.

FYI for anyone struggling with this process going forward (evidently that's not many people as there's very little on the internet about this):

1. Make sure you're logged in as sys/[sys password]. You can change this via SQLPlus if you're not sure by using sqlplus / as sysdba and then use an ALTER statement to change the password.
2. Specify for the input: default OE tablespace "users".
3. Update all the @? to the directory your files are stored.

Comment: Well, are you using the correct password for sys?

Comment: Yes. I've run the statement alter user sys identified by manager; in sqlplus so I believe that's correct.

Comment: Could I trouble you to give me a hand with this again? I had an issue with running it from the hr schema initially, now running correctly as sys.

The next issue I faced was the 'tablespace does not exist' but I've gotten past that by specifying tablespace as users. Now, if you look at the second update, its having trouble finding the file "?/demo/....". What does the ? mean? Where should these files be located in order for this code to find them, as I'm not telling it where to find them from the initial inputs?

Comment: Which version of DB do you have?

Answer (score 1):

The output shows a series of `ORA-01031: insufficient privileges` for activities like CREATE USER.  Clearly you are not running this script whilst connected as SYSDBA account.

The [script itself](https://github.com/oracle/db-sample-schemas/blob/master/order_entry/oe_main.sql) states:

```
rem NOTES
rem   Run as SYS or SYSTEM
```

Note that you need to connect `AS SYSDBA`. It's better to use an OS account that's part of the DBA group.  Check your connection properties in SQL Developer. [See this](http://www.asktheoracle.net/problem-connecting-to-oracle-as-sysdba-from-oracle-sql-developer.html). Or in SQL*Plus you do something like this:

```
SQL> show user
USER is "APC"
SQL> connect / as sysdba
Connected.
SQL> show user
USER is "SYS"
SQL>
```

---

By the way, it's very bad practice to specify the root directory for everything `DEFINE data_path = C:\`.  I hope that's not what you're really doing.  Finding files will be an absolute nightmare.

Comment: I am unequivocally running this code as sys. I've actually made some progress - I'm now seeing amended code in EDIT above.

Comment: Could I trouble you to give me a hand with this again? I had an issue with running it from the hr schema initially, now running correctly as sys.

The next issue I faced was the 'tablespace does not exist' but I've gotten past that by specifying tablespace as users. Now, if you look at the second update, its having trouble finding the file "?/demo/....". What does the ? mean? Where should these files be located in order for this code to find them, as I'm not telling it where to find them from the initial inputs?

Answer (score 0):

Although this is installation is for `12c`, I have found that it does not reckon with that this must be performed against a pluggable database, and not against the container database. It seems it is built for `12C` databases that do not use `cdb/pdb`. To make this work for a `pdb` you have to:

1. beforehand connect with `sys` to the `pdb` where you want the `HR` and `OE schemas`.
2. Edit the `hr_main.sql` and `oe_main` sql lines that do a `CONNECT` and add `@[pdbname]` to it. This has to be done for `CONNECT` with `hr`, `oe` and `sys`

Example: `CONNECT oe/&pass` has to be changed to `CONNECT oe/&pass@[pdb name]`